# Rails tutorial ch11 accoun activation. Why is my activation email not sending with sendgrid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid, railstutorial.org

Currently following michael hartl's rails tutorial on ch 11, account activation. I am using sendgrid to send an account activation email in production. However i receive no email.  The code seems to be working and producing an email template in the heroku logs but iit never sends.  I had a problem before saying that my sendgrid account was not verified and i have solved this. (apart from whitelabelling stage, not sure if this makes adifference). The send grid account is not activated but i am still getting various errors in the heroku logs and i need help in understanding them.

heroku logs: As can be seen from the heroku logs below. Testuser1 is created with email addresss testuser1@testemail.com. then the activation email is generated but never arrives (this is not a real email but i have tried with multiple real ones and get the same error i just used this email to post here)..then there are a few arrors at the end which i don't know how to deal with.

heroku logs:

```
D, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.256730 #6] DEBUG -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276]   SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest", "activation_digest") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "testuser1"], ["email", "testuser1@testemail1.com"], ["created_at", "2017-12-03 06:00:55.183243"], ["updated_at", "2017-12-03 06:00:55.183243"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$SVA7hgBW7lkm63KwUR.gc.W4LFVb.7Zn8oLTg50deBOmJGljcIUv2"], ["activation_digest", "$2a$10$tWF2n2vJI92GDsKX9NfyUuVM/rxghRfPjuJRCvFC/IZ9ooXWymM1W"]]
D, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.258773 #6] DEBUG -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276]    (1.5ms)  COMMIT
I, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.266930 #6]  INFO -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276]   Rendering user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer
I, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.269541 #6]  INFO -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276]   Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer (2.4ms)
I, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.271006 #6]  INFO -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276]   Rendering user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb within layouts/mailer
I, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.271902 #6]  INFO -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276]   Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.7ms)
2017-12-03T06:00:55.494735+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com request_id=b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276 fwd="5.62.43.97" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=475ms status=500 bytes=1891 protocol=https
D, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.425916 #6] DEBUG -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276] UserMailer#account_activation: processed outbound mail in 165.9ms
I, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.491479 #6]  INFO -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276] Sent mail to testuser1@testemail1.com (65.4ms)
D, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.491572 #6] DEBUG -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276] Date: Sun, 03 Dec 2017 06:00:55 +0000
From: noreply@example.com
To: testuser1@testemail1.com
Message-ID: <5a23931768fbc_6333d7d87257c@60d510ea-02dc-4670-96aa-397d82d5d64a.mail>
Subject: Account activation
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_5a23931767b1c_6333d7d8724e9";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


Content-Type: text/plain;
----==_mimepart_5a23931767b1c_6333d7d8724e9
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hi testuser1,

Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:

https://still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com/account_activations/0MwIEqEXZaLzmWJb8KhGOg/edit?email=testuser1%40testemail1.com

----==_mimepart_5a23931767b1c_6333d7d8724e9
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Sample App</h1>

<p>Hi testuser1,</p>

Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:
<p>
</p>

  </body>
</html>

<a href="https://still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com/account_activations/0MwIEqEXZaLzmWJb8KhGOg/edit?email=testuser1%40testemail1.com">Activate</a>

----==_mimepart_5a23931767b1c_6333d7d8724e9--
I, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.491875 #6]  INFO -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 454ms (ActiveRecord: 22.3ms)
F, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.492410 #6] FATAL -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276]   
):
F, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.492467 #6] FATAL -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276] Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: account disabled
F, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.492512 #6] FATAL -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276]   
F, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.492563 #6] FATAL -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276] app/models/user.rb:64:in `send_activation_email'
[b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:25:in `create'
```

account actıvatıons controller:

```
class AccountActivationsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.activate
      log_in user
      flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
    before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: params[:page]) 

  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email #listing 11.36, replaced in user model by send_activation_email-->UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
   User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
   User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      # Handle a successful update.
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user

    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

       # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

        # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true


# Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

    # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end


    # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

    # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_columns(activated: true, activated_at: Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now 
  end

    # Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest,  User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

  private

    # Converts email to all lower-case.
    def downcase_email
      #self.email = email.downcase
      email.downcase!
    end

    # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end
end
```

smpt settings:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'https://still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

errors extracted from heroku logs above:

```
2017-12-03T06:00:55.492517+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.492467 #6] FATAL -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276] Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: account disabled
2017-12-03T06:00:55.492558+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.492512 #6] FATAL -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276]   
2017-12-03T06:00:55.492618+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-12-03T06:00:55.492563 #6] FATAL -- : [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276] app/models/user.rb:64:in `send_activation_email'
2017-12-03T06:00:55.492619+00:00 app[web.1]: [b4f34ac2-105f-474e-aece-91b2ced26276] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:25:in `create'
```

Could this be a problem with the code or a problem with sendgrid setup?  The tutorial does not go into any detail about setting up sendgrid. my send grid account is now active, but as i mentioned i have not set up whitelisting because i dont know what it is. as i have assumed that without it sendgrid will just default to its standard settings. has anyone completed thi spart of the rails tutoiral before? any help welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The email is in your heroku server logs

```
Hi testuser1,

Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:

https://still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com/account_activations/0MwIEqEXZaLzmWJb8KhGOg/edit?email=testuser1%40testemail1.com
```

to have the email sent you need to configure action mailer

This is the [SendGrid official documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html), also there are many discussions online on [how to configure Rails ActionMailer](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how%20to%20configure%20ruby%20on%20rails%20Action%20Mailer&atb=v52-6_b&ia=qa)

Comment: that is strange because i understood from the tutorial that the email should arrive in my inbox. it mentions nothing about any configuration. i will take a look at these links.

Comment: @Owen tutorials are self explanatory. There is no need to post questions on Stackoverflows. They already include all the steps.

Comment: but it didnt include any steps. that's why i posted here. there were more steps than were mentioned in the tutorial. send grid is more complicated to use than the tutorial makes out. the tutorial gave step by step instructions on how to use heroku, github and bitbucket but not sendgrid.

Comment: In fact i had already configured Action Mailer. reading the tutorial on sendgrid thisi is the same as in the rials tutorial. see my configuration above. So this is not the source of the error. Why could i not be receiveing the email in my inbox in production? please see errors above

Comment: @Owen there could be many reason. could be that you did not set the environment variables in heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars or could be that you did not configure all the steps